# Apache still double encoding slashes after correct config

Tags: apache, encoding, proxy, reverse-proxy

So I have a proxy that looks like:

```
ProxyPass /testpath/ http://127.0.0.1:8181/testpath/ nocanon
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

And when I make requests to apache using the boxes IP it works fine with request URI such as /foo%2Fbar. This box has an openvpn tunnel on it and when the request comes from there which has a corporate 10.* ip apache decides to double encode the slash.
If I standup a little server of my own and listen on port 80 I get the correct path from the tunnel, so its not the tunnel, its apache. Any ideas??

I should also note that the path in the access logs is always correct with just %2F.

Comment: This appears to only be when the request line of the http request contains an absolute url:
GET http://host/path HTTP/1.1
Instead of the host and scheme being in the Host header.

Comment: This is correct. Did you find any config that would prevent this?

Comment: I did not, ended up having to change the code that was generating it.